# Explorer is missing half tray icons in XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, notification-area

lately and with no explanation half of the tray icons disappear every time I start up XP SP3. I use Process Explorer (procexp.exe) to look for the missing processes and they still there. When i kill and restart explorer.exe, the tray is complete again. I don't know how to diagnostic or repair the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times this can occur when you log into your user account before Windows XP has fully loaded all its start-up processes.  I tend to wait for my hard drive light to stop blinking before I log in, and that has alleviated the issue for me.

Comment: Ok, make sense. I have only one user that autologin in startup. Is there any way to delay this? Thanks.